# How to create a table to maintain a hierarchy structure in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We need a table to maintain a hierarchy to perform all the CRUD operations.

Sample:

```
 - Karnataka
   - Bangalore
     - Kormangala
   - Hubli
 - Madhya Pradesh
   - Gwalior
 - Delhi
```

I thought of the following structure:

Table 1:

```
State ID(uuid)    Name            childCount
101               Karnataka        2
102               Bangalore        1
103               Kormangala       0
104               Hubli            0
105               Madhya Pradesh   1
106               Gwalior          0
107               Delhi            0
```

Table 2:

```
Parent_Id         child_id
101                102
101                104
102                103
105                106
```

Please suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution :

```
CREATE TABLE state 
 (id int,
 name text,
 child_count int,
 PRIMARY KEY (id));

 CREATE TABLE hierarchy  
 (parent_id int,
 child_id int,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, child_id));
```

child_id must be a clustering column.

Less obvious solution with static columns :

```
 CREATE TABLE state 
 (id int,
 name text static,
 child_count static,
 child_id int,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, child_id));
```

For more information about static columns : https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/refStaticCol.html

I hope this helps